# These 8 lines of python + pandas would take ~1 month to execute, help me speed them up?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, pandas

I have a 30GB csv file with 2 columns, 80M rows. One column has 80M unique elements (emails), the other column 5M uniques (anonymized senders) to which the 80M map many-to-one. I want to output a csv with only the 5M rows: sender, emails sent by sender

This code works in theory, in practice it'd take ~1 month to complete with a Xeon CPU core at 100%

```
df = pd.read_csv('emails.csv')
uni = df.sender_id.unique()
grouped = ((i, ' '.join(df.text[df.sender_id == i])) for i in uni)
with open('/storage/test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    test_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for i in grouped:
        test_writer.writerow(i)
csvfile.close()
```

any idea how to make this faster? I've tried parallelizing it with joblib, but I run out of RAM.

Comment: Maybe mport into an RDBMS and query from there?

Comment: I'd suggest profiling your code with a line profiler, see which lines are taking the majority of the time, and proceed from there.

Comment: If memory use is the main issue, you might try using [``dask.dataframe``](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) which automates parallelization of pandas-like operations. Also, is there any reason you're doing the grouping by hand rather than using a ``groupby``?

Comment: all awesome suggestions, thanks. Yes, I keep running into similar issues, time to learn more about databases, and about profiling. `dask.dataframe` looks great, trying it out now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see problem in this line of code:

```
grouped = ((i, ' '.join(df.text[df.sender_id == i])) for i in uni)
```

which takes O(80M x 5M) to execute. For every sender, it goes over all 80M messages to match the sender, and join the matched emails.

Instead, you can iterate through the emails only once:

```
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.read_csv('emails.csv')
grouped = defaultdict(str)
for i, text in zip(df.sender_id, df.text):
    grouped[i] += text + ' '

with open('/storage/test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    test_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for i in grouped.items():  # use iteritems in Python2
        test_writer.writerow(i)
```

I don't think you need to explicitly close cvsfile if it comes from the "with" statement. Thanks to njzk2 for suggesting defaultdict.

Comment: `grouped.get(i, '')` works too, as would also `grouped = defaultdict(str)` and then `grouped[i] += text + ' '`

Answer (score 1):

I get a factor of ~5 speed improvement on a simple N=10,000 test case by using a pandas groupby/apply and writing the csv from the resulting dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('emails.csv')
grouped = df.groupby('sender_id').apply(lambda group: ' '.join(group.text))
grouped.to_csv('/storage/test.csv')
```

I'd start with this, and continue optimizing from there if it's not sufficient. If memory is an issue, you might turn to [`dask.dataframe`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html), which offers a pandas-like interface to straightforward out-of-core/distributed computation on dataframes.